# error[E0277]: the trait bound is not satisfied for Deserialize<'_>` and Serialize<'_>`

Tags: error, build, upgrade

Hi I am currently upgrading our runtime to Polkadot 1.0 but when I try to build it get the following errors

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MintingRateInfo: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
     --> /home/aibrayanov/Blockchain/metaverse_network/dev/pallets/estate/src/lib.rs:249:3
      |
  249 |         pub minting_rate_config: MintingRateInfo,
      |         ^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `MintingRateInfo`

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `MintingRateInfo: Serialize` is not satisfied
      --> /home/aibrayanov/Blockchain/metaverse_network/dev/pallets/estate/src/lib.rs:61:1
       |
  61   | #[frame_support::pallet]
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `MintingRateInfo`
```

This error occurs despite that both Serialize and Deserialize are enabled for MintingRateInfo type. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/runtime-upgrade/polkadot-v1.0.0)

Comment: Perhaps you could give a more precise link to the snipper of code where Serialize and Deserialize are implemented on MintingRateInfo?

Comment: @jsdw here is the implementation of MintingRateInfo https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/blob/runtime-upgrade/polkadot-v1.0.0/pallets/estate/src/rate.rs

Comment: I can see that the "std" feature is required for Serialize and Deserialize, and presumably the pallet will be compiled without "std", so perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: @jsdw Yeah it was working fine with this configuration until at least serde version 1.0.136. For some reason the Serialization/Deserialization seems to not be supported for the type after.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to see what somebody with more experience compiling pallets chime in then. As an experiment, you could try removing the `cfg(feature = "std")` stuff from the `Serialize`/`Deserialize` derives and see what errors come back, because that's the only thing that I can see that would lead to your error message.